# .NET AMQP client can't connect to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: c#, activemq-artemis

I've installed ActiveMQ on Windows, and I'm able to connect on `localhost:8161` via Chrome, but not through code. The `CreateAsync` instruction never returns. Am I missing something?

[image: code snippet]

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? What client library are you using? Why are you trying to connect your messaging client to the HTTP port (i.e. `8161`) managed by the embedded web server? What happens if you use the AMQP port (i.e. `5672`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pointing your messaging client to the HTTP port (i.e. `8161`) managed by the embedded web server. You should almost certainly be using AMQP port (i.e. `5672`).